# How to determine how many watts my power supply has?

Tags: power-supply

What is the easiest way to see how many watts my power supply has?

Can I see this by viewing something on my computer or Do I open up my PC and look and where on the power supply should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All power supplies are different, so there's no general answer to your question. Most have some kind of label on them that should include their max power, though.

Comment: Thanks, I found a label that said Max Power 480 Watts. Is that the rating?

Comment: Sure sounds like it.

Comment: Every PC power supply has at least +5V and +12V output, often -12V and newer ones +3.3V too. I suggest you to read Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_power_supply) to understand what does this power number indicate.